# IDLE is suddenly crashing on Mac (OS Sierra 10.12.3)

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I'm completely new to programming and I'm taking an online course on Python. I've installed Python 3.4 on my Mac (OS Sierra 10.12.3) and have been happily using IDLE for about a week, but suddenly today I can't open IDLE. The icon bounces for 2 seconds and then closes itself. I've tried reinstalling Python, installing and reinstalling ActiveTcl 8.6.4, restarting my Mac, and nothing works. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow isn't for product support questions.

Comment: You should be able to launch it from the command-line using `idle3`.  At least if it crashes there you should get an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up installing a newer version of Python and it seems to be working now. Sorry for posting something that is off-topic, I didn't know.

Comment: Questions about Python installation and startup malfunctions are on-topic for python-list https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list.  Python-list is mirrored at news.gmane.org as gmane.comp.python.general, which is what I use for both reading and posting.